# backbone-pageable remove() uses invalid url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm relatively new to Backbone and I'm trying to use a PageableCollection in my application.

https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable

Could someone please point me, what am I doing wrong? I'm using backbone 1.0.0

I have a collection and a model defined like this:

```
var VoteList = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
    model: Vote,
    url: config.service + 'votes'
});

var Vote = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () {
        return config.service + 'vote/' + this.id;
    }
});
```

Later in the application:

```
this.collections.voteList = new VoteList([], {mode: "client", state: {pageSize: 12}});
....
this.collections.voteList.remove(options.model);
```

PageableCollection.remove() method fires a DELETE event which uses the URL of VoteList collection(?) to access a web service which in turn produces me an error 405 "Method not allowed" as a DELETE method is supposed to have an {id}

```
@DELETE
@Path("/vote/{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void deleteVoting(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    log.info("deleting " + id.toString());
}
```

When I remove pagination just by instantiating normal Backbone.Collection

```
var VoteList = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... });
```

everything works as expected, Backbone uses a model url + id when deleting. So my question is how to make the PageableCollection to behave just in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This morning got a mail from the plugin author, it appears to be a known bug in Backbone 1.0.0. I guess it will gone away with version 1.0.1

Please see this thread: https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable/issues/70

To solve problem now I used a latest 'master' branch of Backbone which has this issue fixed:

https://raw.github.com/jashkenas/backbone/master/backbone.js

Alternatively, if you can't for some reason use a development branch, a temporary solution like this will also work:

```
var Vote = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.url = function () {
            return config.service + 'vote/' + this.get('id')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrading to backbone 1.1.0** seems to resolve this problem.

I ran into the same exact issue with backbone 1.0.0 collections extended by backbone-pageable.

*Heads up!* Be sure to keep an eye on the [1.1 upgrade notes](http://backbonejs.org/#upgrading) since backbone 1.1 isn't fully compatible to 1.0 code, such as`options`passed to views are no longer automatically available as `this.options`.